# Creating a list of non-repetitive elements from repetitive-elemets list. Using list-comprehansion only

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, non-repetitive

How can I convert  this "for-loop" below to "list-comprehension?
I want to create a list of non-repetitive elements from repetitive-elemets list.

```
many_colors = ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'black', 'blue']

colors = []
for c in many_colors:
  if not c in colors:
    colors.append(c)
# colors = ['red', 'blue', 'black']
```

I tried this (below) but error occurs that colors are not defined.

```
colors = [c for c in many_colors if not c in colors]
```

Comment: Is the sequence important?

Comment: You are creating `colors`, which also means you should not reference it before it actually is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) in python which represents an unordered collection of unique elements.

Use:

```
colors = list(set(many_colors))
print(colors)
```

This prints:

```
['red', 'black', 'blue']
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a set to make your life easier:

```
colors = [c for c in set(many_colors)]
```

Answer (score -1):

`colors` only exists *after* the completion of the comprehension.
A comprehension might not even be optimal. You can do

```
colors = list(set(colors))
```

And if you want to keep the order of occurrence:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

colors = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(many_colors))
```